# createWindowEx failed exception

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

`createWindowEx` failed exception is thrown by my server which is using `overbyteICS` dll in .net C# windowsforms.

I have a server which handles large number of clients throughout the day. But when the total connections(i.e Connection and disconnections altogether) count reaches to 10000 the above error appears and the server stops accepting user connections and also hangs the machine.

Comment: Sounds like your library is using a hidden window per connection. Windows are relatively expensive, so you might expect `CreateWindowEx` to start failing when you create thousands of windows.

Comment: So is there any solution for that??

Comment: File a bug against the library or use a different library...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Roger, but let's confirm it first - When this error occurs, run `SPY++` from MicrosoftVisualStudio\Tools in the start Menu and look through the window tree. Expand the branches and look for duplicates of some windows. Surely there will be many of them, but you are interested in hundreds and thousands of copies. If you hit that, then it's what Roger said... ...and there's almost no solution other that periodically restarting the connection-server process (or whole machine, just in case) just to be sure it doesnt hang (of course, server restart will irritate the users almost as much..), or fixing/patching/reimplementing the connection-server process to be more resource-friendly..

Note that while opening a hidden window per single connection is a **very** wasteful approach, it still shuold *not* hang the machine. It simply should drop the connections that it cannot handle. Here, it seems it has no limits implemented at all, which is a bug.

edit: on pre-NT (i.e. win9x) the limit is hardcoded. On NT class systems, you can try to tweak the pool:

http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2007/02/07/max-num-of-open-windows-under-xp-2003-vista-resolved.aspx

but still, I'd consider that as a last restort, as problem will return when number of connection rises again. First, try to ping the server developers to fix that permanently..

Comment: If you really hit _that_ problem, then hardly. IIRC, the max number of windows is a hardcoded limit, but as I've said, unless you use a very old Windows version, it is already quite high. You may try running the SPY++ and checking what **other** programs generate window and then closing them to free up more handles, but well, you may find it hard to manually find and close next 10000 windows :) You may configure the OS to run less services and programs at startup to drop the handle count.

Comment: note: correction: it was hardcoded in old systems, now it seems it can be configured a little. see my edit to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You diagnosed it well.  Yes, a CreateWindowEx() failure and 10,000 belong together.  10,000 is the default user32 object quota for a process.  In other words, a single process isn't allowed to create more than 10,000 windows.  This is a counter-measure against apps that leak window handles, a very common bug.  The total number of windows that can be created in a session is a limited resource, having one process consume them all would cause outright failure, you couldn't shut down Windows anymore.

Clearly it is not a leak in your case.  You can find temporary relief by changing a registry setting, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\USERProcessHandleQuota.  Reboot to make it effective.

Increasing from 10,000 to the maximum of 18,000 should be okayish if the machine doesn't otherwise run processes that require a lot of windows.  Something you can see with Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.  Choose View + Select Columns and tick USER objects.  Also tick GDI objects and Handles while you are at it, other resources that have a quota.

Long term, this behavior does not scale well.  You'll need to find the code that creates a window handle for every web request and fix it.

Comment: Yes, we were right i checked with the task manager about the USER object and i found out that on every connection user objects gets incremented but its not getting decremented on disconnection. When the user objects reaches 10000 my server stops accepting connections. So if possible please provide me the solution to tackle the problem. On disconnection event i am disposing the client object with is collected by GC runs on timer.

Comment: That's an outright leak.  If you are sure you are using the DLL correctly then you'll need to get support from its owner to get the bug fixed.

Comment: I am not able to get support on this from the owner, isn't there any other way, or tool to prevent this ?